# Turn 'Remember Me' checkbox in to a submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently am using Rails' "Devise" plugin to handle login/authentication. I am using a very basic `form_for` tag to handle the log-in form. Here is the code:

```ruby
<div class="well-outer splash-signin-block">
  <div class="well-inner">
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <div>
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_session_path, html: {
        class: "form-inline"
      }) do |f| %>
        <p><%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email", autofocus: true %></p>
        <p><%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %></p>
        <p>
          <%= f.submit 'Sign in', class:"btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me, class: "checkbox" %>
          <%= f.label :remember_me %>
        </p>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I would like to change that "Remember me" checkbox in to a button. The user experience would be that they could either click "Sign in" (the default action) or they could click "Remember me" to sign in persistently.

Behind the scenes, I imagine this would work by using a hidden field that sets the `resource[remember_me]` property to "1". However as a rails newbie I don't know how to go about coding this. I imagine it will need some javascript and that is fine, but googling has only turned up AJAX-y stuff and I don't think that's necessary. I won't shy away from it if it is necessary, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461790/multiple-submit-buttons-forms-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a button with some id, then use javascript to bind to the click event of that button. When the button is clicked, you want to change the value of a hidden field. If you were using jQuery, it would be something like...

```
   $('#id_of_button').click(function() {
     $('#id_of_hidden_field').val("true");
   });
```

Then you just check for that value in the controller like you normally would.

If you're not using jQuery it's not much more work, I just don't know it off the top of my head. Btw this code should be located in a .js file in your assets/javascript folder

Comment: How would I define the hidden field? I see there is a "form.hidden_field" helper, but I assume there is something more complex than simply changing the check_box to a hidden_field. Right? Also, is it definitely `val("true")` or could it be `val("1")`? That confuses me as well.

Comment: "I assume there is something more complex than simply changing the check_box to a hidden_field" - Nope, that's pretty much exactly what you'll do. Just give it :id => 'remember_me_button' or something similar. You can have the val be anything you want, it will come over in the params like normal. If you're still confused feel free to ask more questions, I was a rails newbie about a month ago so I know how it feels to start out!

Comment: Thanks! Ok, got another one for you before I can try this out (although it's looking good so far!) - where do I put this javascript code? As a clue, I'm using devise, and to modify this particular page the file I edit is app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb - can I just drop the code in, say, app/assets/javascripts/devise.js? (I happen to be using coffeescript, so extensions may vary.)

Comment: That should work fine. The code I gave you should work if you're using jQuery, you'll just need to substitute in the right ids.

Comment: NAILED it. Thanks Kenny! It's actually quite interesting, I think, that the correct solution involved almost no special markup save for four lines of coffeescript code and one hidden field. I assumed there would be a lot more inconvenience to deal with.