# insert multiple records to a single table from a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Generally if we can create only 1 record, say 1 user at a time from the form. But what if I want to create multiple users from a single form? There are no associations with other models. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make a form with an array of users params .e.g

```
<%= from_tag '/users/create_multiple' do %>
 <%= text_field_tag "users[][name]" %>
 <%= text_field_tag "users[][name]" %>
<% end %>
```

In UsersController:

```
def create_multiple
 params[:users].each do |user|
  user = User.create(user)
 end
end
```

You can add validation code as per your wishes,
visit here how to pass form params for multiple records http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#basic-structures

Comment: But, by exemple, if you create new users following this way, it will validate each user, supposing that you cannot use special chars on username, if you create each user: User1, User2, Us&r3, User4@, users 1 and 2 will be created, user 3 and 4 will be not created, but you'll be redirected to the same form like user 1 and 2 wasn't created too, what's the rails logic to solve this issue? I tried something like using " before validation do ", without success. ANy Suggestion?

Comment: @drmwndr before create you can validate user and save in array display error message this user is not valid.Consider uploading csv with users data i am rendering UI which is not valid with error message

Comment: @Amar that's what i've been tried, without any success. After validation, instead rails redirect to form again with the errors markup, it brings the error: "undefined method `model_name' for Enumerator:Class". I'm not trying a very massive insertion, which demands CSV.

Answer (score 1):

One option is, write as many forms that you want for each model and submit all the forms once with Jquery.

This link will help you with submitting multiple forms

[Multiple submit buttons/forms in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461790/multiple-submit-buttons-forms-in-rails)